# Purple flash when logging in

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen, gdm

I am using the same background image for both my GDM background and my gnome wallpaper. However, when I log in, I see a purple splash. I have no clue where this splash comes from.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhh8c.jpg)

Where does this splash come from and how to I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried several things but none of them did the trick.

I finally got rid of the purple flash by installing `gnome-session` and using GNOME as the default

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

The procedure is described in more detail in this thread (for 17.10)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383902